# Rails 3: form_for ignoring setting method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

A user has the ability to edit their credit card information, like so:

CreditCardsController:

```
class CreditCardsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    respond_to :js

    def edit
      @cc = current_user.credit_cards.where(:id => params[:id]).first
      respond_with @cc
  end

end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @cc, :remote => true, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
    <div id="cancel-subscription" class="modal-content">
        <div class="header dotted-border">
            <h2>Billing Information</h2>
            <p>Edit the fields below to update your information</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content dotted-border">
            <h2>Credit Card</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

For some reason the `form_for`is ignorning the `:method` option even if I leave it off. It keeps getting set to `post`. That is not correct since I am editing/updating a CC entry. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I believe this is normal. To do with how Rails handles PUT and DELETE in forms. Is the update action being called?

Comment: Yeah, I was pulling a brain fart.. I forgot that Rails adds a hidden input to the form with the _method set to whatever you put it as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding

```
 :html => { :method => put }
```

will not work, because form_for generate _methode hidden element with form on update and delete.

just using

```
 :method => "put"
```

in form may work

Comment: thanks for pointing out something I was goofing on! I forgot Rails adds a method hidden input to control which method is hit upon submitting the form